# Realm query of empty RLMArray

Tags: swift, realm

I have a subclass of RLMObject (Transaction) that holds an RLMArray of another RLMObject (Split).  I would like to query all Transactions with no splits (RLMArray of size 0).  What would the predicate look like?  The below NSPredicate does not work.  I get an error.

```
Transaction.allObjects().objectsWithPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "splits == nil"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do following:

```
Transaction.objectsWhere("NOT ANY splits IN %@", Split.allObjects())
```

Just for your information, 
Since `Transaction.allObjects().objectsWithPredicate()` and `Transaction.objectsWithPredicate()` are exactly the same meaning. So calling `allObjects()` is not required.